# How does Sakurai reduce a product to a commutator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

The following section is from *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai; can any one help me finding out how this is done?

> In contrast, if we follow approach 2, we obtain
>   \begin{align}
> \vert\alpha\rangle&\to\vert\alpha\rangle \\
> \mathbf{x}&\to\left(1+\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right)\mathbf x\left(1-\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right) \\
> &=\mathbf x + \left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)\left[\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf x',\,\mathbf x\right]\tag{this line} \\
> &=\mathbf x +d\mathbf x'
> \end{align}
>   We leave it as an exercise for the reader to show that both approaces lead to the same result for the expectation value of $\mathbf x$:
>   $$\langle\mathbf x\rangle\to\langle\mathbf x\rangle+\langle d\mathbf x'\rangle$$

Sakurai just mentions that if operator is changed but state kets are kept frozen but he left mathematics for students.

Comment: I don't know if that is your problem, but he is neglecting terms of order higher than one in $d\mathbf{x}$ to understand the effect of an infinitesimal transformation.

Comment: (1+a)b(1-a) = (b+ab)(1-a) = b+ab-ba-aba, neglecting the last term we get b+ab-ba which is equal to b+[a,b]

Comment: My question how it is mathematically done?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding,
\begin{align}
&\left(1+\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right)\mathbf x\left(1-\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right) \\
&= \left(\mathbf x + \frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\mathbf x\right)\left(1-\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right) \\
&=\mathbf x + \frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\mathbf x - \mathbf x\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar} - \left(\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\right)^2 \\
\end{align}
But the last term is of order $(d\mathbf x')^2$, so it vanishes. Then 
\begin{align}
&\to \mathbf x + \frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar}\mathbf x - \mathbf x\frac{i\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf{x}'}{\hbar} \\
&=\mathbf x + \left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\right)\left[\mathbf p\cdot d\mathbf x',\,\mathbf x\right] \\
&=\mathbf x +d\mathbf x'.
\end{align}

Comment: What about the last step where from dx' comes and how?

Comment: How last step is done?